# Magento 2 API Order Items, convert Json to table using php

Tags: magento2, php, api, json

I am tring to create a table dinamically with the products of a Magento order using API result.

I have the following PHP code to dinamically generate a table with Json content

```
$data = json_decode($resp, true);

/*Initializing temp variable to design table dynamically*/
$temp = "<table>";
 
/*Defining table Column headers depending upon JSON records*/
$temp .= "<tr><th>Order ID</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Sku</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Nome</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Quantità</th></tr>";
 
/*Dynamically generating rows & columns*/
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data["items"]); $i++)
{
$temp .= "<tr>";
$temp .= "<td>" . $data["items"][$i]["items"] . "</td>";
$temp .= "<td>" . $data["items"][$i]["sku"] . "</td>";
$temp .= "<td>" . $data["items"][$i]["name"] . "</td>";
$temp .= "<td>" . $data["items"][$i]["qty_ordered"] . "</td>";
$temp .= "</tr>";
}
 
/*End tag of table*/
$temp .= "</table>";
 
/*Printing temp variable which holds table*/
echo $temp;
```

In this way is not working because the products are in the second deep "items" node (json)

```
{
    "items": [{
        "items": [{
            "name": "Product 1",
            "order_id": 54228,
            "qty_ordered": 2,
            "sku": "190289855757"
        }, {
            "name": "Product 2",
            "order_id": 54228,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "sku": "4062051502434"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Decoded version

```
Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Product 1 [order_id] => 54228 [qty_ordered] => 2 [sku] => 190289855757 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Product 2 [order_id] => 54228 [qty_ordered] => 1 [sku] => 4062051502434 ) ) ) ) )
```

I used the following API call

```
https://mywebsite.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&fields=items[entity_id]&fields=items[items[order_id,sku,name,qty_ordered]]&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1
```

Is there a way to get just the second node items result or a way to set the **for** so that it counts just the second deep node containing "item"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code.

```
/*Dynamically generating rows & columns*/

foreach($data["items"] as $productdata)
{
    $temp .= "<tr>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $productdata["sku"] . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $productdata["name"] . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $productdata["qty_ordered"] . "</td>";
    $temp .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Using this solution returned me just a cell valorized with value "Array" see screesnhot https://nimb.ws/KDRBQx

Comment: I update the answer, try that one, that will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately is giving an //Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: I update the answer, can you check that thnigs, is that working or not.

Comment: Hi, it is not working on my side.
I updated the post with the jeson response and decoded